# Access variable inside class

Tags: php, class

I'm new in OO php, and I'm trying to access $my_array string (or it is a property):

```
class Something extends MAIN
{
    private static $instance;



public static function newInstance()
    {
        if( !self::$instance instanceof self ) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $my_array = array('test1','test2');
    }
}
```

Tried with this:

```
$int = Something::newInstance();
echo $int->my_array;
echo Something::my_array
```

But nothing works. What is the problem? EDIT: I must mention that I shouldn't change anything inside Something class. Or it is impossible to do this without making a change inside Soemthing class?

Comment: if you cant change `something`, then extend it, and overwrite the __constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`$my_array` is now a local variable in your method (=function in a class) and therefor cannot be read outside of that method. Change it like this to make it a 'property'*) of the object.

```
class Something extends MAIN
{
    private static $instance;
    public $my_array;

    function newInstance() { ... } // Left out for brevity

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // Use $this to reference the instance, in the way that self references the class.
        $this->my_array = array('test1','test2');
    }
}
```

Then use

```
$int = Something::newInstance();
echo $int->my_array;
```

*) PHP calls it a property, but in most languages a property is a definition that referes to getter and setter methods or directly to an (often private) variable in the class. In PHP, that variable itself is called a property.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possoble to access my_array without changing class Something?

Comment: same, but __construct will not be called.

Comment: No. Like I said it is a local variable now, which you cannot access. You have to store it *somewhere* to be able to access it. Either you have to store it in a property, or in a variable that is outside of the class altogether.

Comment: @rufinus Yes it will. The static newInstance creates an instance if it doesn't exist yet. Basically it behaves like a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

$my_array is local to the constructor . You'll need to declare it in such a way that it has the scope of class. You'll have to do it as

```
class Something extends MAIN
{
    private static $instance;
    public $my_array = array();

// Rest code
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but also incomplete. You should also set the variable in the constructor in a different way `($this->myarray = ..)` otherwise you will still set the local variable. You don't strictly need to initialize the property since it is overwritten in the constructor anyway, but that is okay.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Something extends MAIN {

    private static $instance;
    public static $my_array;

    public static
    function newInstance() {
        if (!self::$instance instanceof self) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        self::$my_array = array('test1', 'test2');
    }
}
```

You can assign a value to `$my_array` directly without to be in the constructor function.

```
public static $my_array = array('test1', 'test2');
```

and remove this line from constructor

```
self::$my_array = array('test1', 'test2');
```

---

When usage:

```
$int = Something::newInstance();
print_r(Something::$my_array);
```

Comment: This will work. Question is whether $my_array should be static, since it is set in the constructor, but that is for OP to figure out.